# How to get DimensionReduce and FeatureSpacePlot to act consistently?

Tags: plotting, interactive

The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FeatureSpacePlot.html) for `FeatureSpacePlot` does not appear to be consistent with it's behavior in 13.1

The documentation indicates you can wrap the inputs to FeatureSpacePlot, to permit actions to be performed on them when you mouse over them in the plot.  That doesn't seem to work.

The last example in the "Scope -> Wrappers" section in the documentation is:

```
data = EntityValue[
   EntityClass["Country", "Europe"], {"FlagImage", "Name", 
    "Population", "Area"}, "PropertyAssociation"];
FeatureSpacePlot[Map[Tooltip[Button[{#Population, #Area}, Speak[#Name]], #FlagImage] &, data]]
```

The image given in the documentation is below.  With the implication that if you mouse over a dot, you'll get an image of the flag, and if you click a dot, Mathematica will `Speak` the country name.

[image]

When I run this same example in 13.1, I get:

[image]

The tooltips returned are "Units" and clicking just brings up the "edit image" widget instead calling `Speak`.

How to get the behavior like in the documentation?